# Como somar um número a um array?

Tags: python-3.x, array, funções, numpy, soma

Olá! Tudo bem com vocês?

Estou fazendo um código e precisei definir uma função:

```
def sigmoid (v):
return 1/(1+np.exp(-v))
```

Só que o que estou atribuindo para a função é um array 2d.

A minha dúvida é: na teoria estou somando 1 com um array 2d. isto era para dar erro, não? Mas está funcionando sem problema. Ele está fazendo o cálculo da função sigmoide para todos os elementos do array. Meu pensamento está incorreto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, seu pensamento está correto (em tese), mas essa característica é proposital e muitíssimo bem-vinda. Esse comportamento acontece porque numpy aplica uma prática chamada ***broadcasting***. Quando você faz uma operações entre arrays com uma quantidade diferente de dimensões, o de menor dimensão é 'replicado' quantas vezes forem necessárias para passar pela operação com o de maior dimensão.

Veja a definição da prática dada [na documentação do numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

> The term broadcasting describes how numpy treats arrays with different shapes during arithmetic operations. Subject to certain constraints, the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes. Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python. It does this without making needless copies of data and usually leads to efficient algorithm implementations.

Assim, se você somar um escalar a um vetor ou matriz, o escalar vai ser somado a cada elemento do vetor ou matriz. Se somar um vetor a uma matriz, o vetor vai ser somado a cada coluna da matriz (se as dimensões forem compatíveis).

[Este link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html) tem uma explicação gráfica mais clara, caso ainda tenha dúvidas.